# Sorting nested lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Given is a nested list, with the following markup (and sadly can't be changed at this moment).
I want to sort this list (and all nested lists by the 'a'-tag title.) 
The first div (which is not nested in 'li') should be used to sort the 'ul'-siblings.

Performance is also important, as this list can easly contain more than 100 items, but less than I guess 1000. (I'm not sure if this might become a performance issue)

```
<ul>
    <div class="bioResult"><a href="">Test</a></div>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <div class="bioResult"><a href="">C Departmnet</a></div>
            <li>
                <div class="bioResult"><a href="">C</a></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I already struggled around and got the nested list sorting done, but I couldn't get my head around the 'ul'-siblings sorting, as it didn't work as I thought it could work. :)

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrw9de0f/8/).

Plugins aren't an option at this moment.

Comment: if it is coming from database you can sort it by your DBMS before it encoded to json

Comment: At this point, I don't have much control of it's source and how it's rendered. :(

Comment: is there a finite depth of these lists? could you provide a static version of that the ideal output would be? (im confused in your example by what you expect to happen with the two `ul` in the one `li` next to the one `ul` in the one `li`. Perhaps your example could benefit from some unique ids to make discussion about it less confusing?

Comment: The list could be infinite (Altough, this might never happen). I updated my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrw9de0f/8/) to the 'real' markup, but I edited out confidential stuff. ;) I need to get 'Test & Test', 'C#' and 'Ruby on Rails' sorted, but couldn't figure out how yet.

Comment: You can't have `<div>` as direct descendant of `<ul>`.

Comment: I know that the markup is currently a bit strange, but I can't change it at this moment as I'm not the creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting everything is a matter of appending all nodes to their respective parents in alphabetical order.

```
function uCase(elem) {
    return $.trim( $(elem).text().toUpperCase() )
}
function compareFirstLink(a, b) {
    var A = uCase( $(a).first('a') ),
        B = uCase( $(b).first('a') );       
    return (A > B) ? 1 : -1;
}
$(function () {
    var $sortables = $("ul:has(div:first-child), li:not(.fixedOrder)");
    $sortables.sort(compareFirstLink).each(function () {
        this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
    });
});
```

Comment: @Patte I'm not certain that `ul:has(div:first-child)` will select *only* the correct nodes. Please double-check with your document.

Comment: Do you mean that I should look in the DOM for a more descriptive class / id too use in my selector?

Comment: @Patte Well, either that or you use something like `$("li:not(.fixedOrder)").add( $("ul > div").parent() )`. My point is that `ul:has(div:first-child)` selects `ul` that contain a `div:first-child` *anywhere*, not necessarily those where the `div` is the first child of that `ul` (which was the intention).