# Get item / object from list variable (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working with "sortable" jQuery elements and trying to re-order them from the application. Somewhat [following this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067602/jquery-sortable-change-the-order-by-js)

What I've done is:

1) Create a list of sortable items. Everything works fine

2) Add all the items to this ListItem variable and delete the original list

```
    var ListItems = $('#lstSortablePSU').find('li');
    $('#lstSortablePSU').empty();
```

3) Now in a loop I need to look up 'li' elements with specific id's in the ListItems variable and add them back to the sortable list container.
Something like:

```
$('#lstSortablePSU').append(ListItems['#li' + PSUname]);
```

But I guess this /\ looks up by index not key of the array.

FYI: My ListItems variable looks like this after step 2

[image]

Comment: To clarify and simplify:
Given the "ListItems" variable above, how do I retrieve an element by matching the ID?
So for example I need to get element #liDVDD33, so the result should be same as doing ListItems[5]

Comment: If you want to get the element with ID `liDVDD33`, why don't you do `$('#liDVDD33')`?

Comment: because I'm not trying to get this element from the DOM, but rather from an array "ListItems"

Comment: but *why*? It's entirely unclear what effect you want to achieve. Don't tell me how you want to do it before you told me what you want to do in the first place. compare XY-problem.

Comment: I have a list of  HTML items "li"s that are in some order within a container. I need to re-order these items within a container based on another list. So, what I do, is save all the items into an array "ListItems", remove them from the HTML container, and then add them back in, one at a time in the necessary order.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm on a mobile device right now, so I can't write it down for you, but I've written an earlier answer that's a pretty good fit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27418170/18771

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to toggle the visibility of list items based on whether their IDs are in an array of reference values.

Well, let's do exactly that.

```
var refValues = ['various', 'ids'];

$('#lstSortablePSU li').toggle(function () {
    var refId = this.id.replace(/^li/, '');

    return $.inArray(refValues, refId) > -1;
});
```

Note that `.toggle()` accepts `true` or `false` to show or hide elements, but it also accepts a function that *calculates* that value.